# Scrape ajax content from site

Tags: python, ajax

There is a site [researcherid](http://www.researcherid.com).
On author page, for example, http://www.researcherid.com/rid/A-7364-2016 i need to retrieve information from `Citation metrics` window. That`s the window generated by ajax. How can i do it with Python ? What tools i have for it?
I tried:

```
payload = {'key': '721889',
       'listid': 'LIST1',
       'displayName': 'My Publications', 'publicProfile': 'true', '_': ''
       }

r = requests.post('http://www.researcherid.com/rid/A-7364-2016',
              data=payload, headers={
                  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
              })
print(r.text)
```

But it does`t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)'s webdriver tools in order to get dynamically loaded content. Simply create a webdriver instance, go to `Citation metrics` page and load source into python. After that, you can scrape content with libraries such as [`LXML`](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) or [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).